# Hash each string retrieved from text file one by one

Tags: vb.net

I have start a new application to hash strings retrieved from text file.
But i can not sort out the way to load from text to list box and hash one by one save on settings and clear the list box and load all the content from my settings.
Well i have sort all the code but i can not find the way to hash all the strings loaded on the list box.
In this moment it only hash the last string
and i need to hash one by one and add to listbox 2

This is my code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim md5 As MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
    Dim inputBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim hash As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        sb.Append(hash(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next
    Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog()
    openfile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim myfile As String = openfile.FileName
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
        For Each line As String In allLines

            ListBox1.Items.Add(line)

            TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
            TextBox3.Text = line
            TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
            My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(TextBox3.Text + "<--->" + TextBox2.Text)

            My.Settings.Save()

            ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        Next
        For Each item In My.Settings.md5_hashes
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If

    'TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
    'ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text + "<--->" + TextBox2.Text)


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. If your aim is to hash each line in the file then surely you need code to compute a hash inside the loop that accesses each line in the file. You only compute one hash there and it's before you even open the file. Maybe you should try writing down the steps you actually need to perform and then writing code to implement those steps. If you do that, I very much doubt that you'll end up opening the file and then not computing any hashes. You should know EXACTLY what your code is supposed to do before you write it and you clearly don't.

Comment: well yes i want to hash each line from the imported file

Comment: well in fact yes i want to hash each line of text file and insert it on listbox all one by one but i don t get were i fail

Comment: Well then, where is your code inside the loop that accesses each line of the file to do the hashing then?  Like I said, make sure that you understand what your code has to do before you write it. If that means picking up a pen and paper and writing down the steps then that's what you should do.  If you did that then you would obviously have a step for hashing the current line as you loop through the lines and if your code didn't include an implementation of that step then the issue would be obvious.

Comment: I Just  Get Solved now its works like i wanted

Comment: You should add an answer and provide your solution. That way, we can tell you if there's anything wrong with it and others can benefit from the solution.  Also, it indicates to everyone that the problem has been resolved so people won't waste their time opening the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact it is very easy but i don t see before jmcilhinney told me to right on paper all before to code tank you for the great help to see were i need to go.
It is just front of me the solution

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog()
    openfile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim myfile As String = openfile.FileName
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
        For Each line As String In allLines

            ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
            Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

                ' Convert to byte array and get hash
                Dim dbytes As Byte() =
                     hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line))

                ' sb to create string from bytes
                Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

                ' convert byte data to hex string
                For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
                    sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
                Next n

                ListBox1.Items.Add(sBuilder.ToString)
            End Using
        Next

        For Each item In My.Settings.md5_hashes
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next

    End If

    'TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
    'ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text + "<--->" + TextBox2.Text)


End Sub
Shared Function GetHash(theInput As String) As String

    Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

        ' Convert to byte array and get hash
        Dim dbytes As Byte() =
             hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theInput))

        ' sb to create string from bytes
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        ' convert byte data to hex string
        For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
        Next n

        Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Using

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: One thing I would say is that there's no need to create a new `MD5` object for each line of the file.  You can just create one and reuse it.  You can also create a hex `String` from a `Byte` array in one line: `myHexString = String.Concat(myByteArray.Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))`.

Comment: i tanks for the replay and help

Comment: Well in fact wen i run the application on visual basic 2012 in Debug Mode Every Thing Go Right But Then Wen I Try To open The App With Out Visual Studio Its Come Nulled exception this is my error

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MD5_Hashing.Form2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\monchique-discovery\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MD5 Hashing\MD5 Hashing\Form2.vb:line 31
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)